# Как работать с RAR-архивами в C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Как работать с RAR-архивами в С#? К примеру, есть архив *.rar*, в нём файлы.
 Необходимо прочитать названия файлов, содержащихся в этом архиве.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Библиотек для работы с RAR довольно много, выбирайте на вкус:

- [SharpCompress](https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress) (ранее [NUnrar](http://nunrar.codeplex.com/))
- [SevenZipSharp](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/)
- [SevenZipLib](http://sevenziplib.codeplex.com/)
- Командная строка (unrar бесплатен, в отличие от упаковщика).
- На у если вам нужны только имена файлов в архиве, то это вообще реализуется на коленке в несколько строчек, формат файла открыт.

На большом СО есть вопрос: [How to extract a rar file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238173/how-to-extract-a-rar-file-in-c)

Comment: Да, нужны только имена файлов в архиве!!!

Answer (score 2):

Для работы можно использовать одну из следующих библиотек:
1. **7z.dll** -> http://dev.nomad-net.info/articles/sevenzipinterface
2. **SevenZipSharp** -> http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com

Еще:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238173/how-to-extract-a-rar-file-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте эти библиотеки http://nunrar.codeplex.com/ или http://sharpcompress.codeplex.com/